# How to add a Fields on click of button in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver, generate, form-fields

how to add text field when I click on add button. which is in the App bar. when I click on the add button it will add FOur field which I have already created in this Example code I've tried. SO please can anyone help. Your help can make my day :).

in This code there Four fields like this. _buildidentificationtype1,_builddocumentnumber1,_buildexpirydate1,_buildissuingauthority1
I want generate these four field when i am click on add button.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:datetime_picker_formfield/datetime_picker_formfield.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_form_builder/flutter_form_builder.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:tudo/src/modules/bsp_signup/bsp_licensed_signup_terms/bsp_licensed_signup_terms_page.dart';
import 'package:tudo/src/modules/bsp_signup/bsp_signup_common_model.dart';
import 'package:tudo/src/styles/colors.dart';

import 'package:tudo/src/utils/navigation_helper.dart';
import 'package:tudo/src/utils/validator.dart';
import 'package:tudo/src/widgets/tudo_selection_widget/TudoConditionWidget.dart';
import 'package:tudo/src/widgets/tudo_text_widget/TudoTextWidget.dart';

class BspUnlicensedSignupPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = "/bspUnlicensedSignup";
  final BspSignupCommonModel bspSignupCommonModel;

  BspUnlicensedSignupPage({
    Key key,
    @required this.bspSignupCommonModel,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BspUnlicensedSignupPageState createState() =>
      _BspUnlicensedSignupPageState();
}

class _BspUnlicensedSignupPageState extends State<BspUnlicensedSignupPage> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  List<Object> images = List<Object>();
  Future<File> _imageFile;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    debugPrint(
        'BSP SIGNUP DATA: ${widget.bspSignupCommonModel.businessPhoneNo}');
    debugPrint('BSP SIGNUP DATA: ${widget.bspSignupCommonModel.businessYear}');
    debugPrint(
        'BSP SIGNUP DATA: ${widget.bspSignupCommonModel.numberofEmployees}');
    debugPrint('BSP SIGNUP DATA: ${widget.bspSignupCommonModel.businessType}');
    debugPrint(
        'BSP SIGNUP DATA: ${widget.bspSignupCommonModel.businessLegalName}');
    setState(() {
      images.add("Add Image");
      images.add("Add Image");
      images.add("Add Image");
      images.add("Add Image");
      images.add("Add Image");
    });
  }

  bool informationislegitimate = false;
  DateTime expirydate1 = DateTime.now();
  DateTime expirydate2 = DateTime.now();

  final format = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  final format2 = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  final TextEditingController clrbusinesslicense = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController clrbusinesslicense2 = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController clrissuingauthority = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController clrissuingauthority2 = TextEditingController();
  String _licenseno;
  String _licenseno2;
  String illusingauthority;
  String illusingauthority2;
  List<String> _type2 = <String>[
    'Passport',
    'Driving License',
    'Voter ID card',
    'Ration Card',
    'Aadhar'
        'Other Id'
  ];
  String type2 = 'Passport';
  List<String> _type = <String>[
    'Passport',
    'Driving License',
    'Voter ID card',
    'Ration Card',
    'Aadhar'
        'Other Id'
  ];
  String type = 'Passport';
  Map<String, String> _formdata = {};
  var _myPets = List<Widget>();
  int _index = 1;

  void _add() {
    int keyValue = _index;
    _myPets = List.from(_myPets)
      ..add(Column(
        key: Key("${keyValue}"),
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            leading: Text('Pet $_index : '),
            title: TextField(
              onChanged: (val) => _formdata['pet${keyValue - 1}'] = val,
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Text('Name of Pet $_index : '),
            title: TextField(
              onChanged: (val) {
                _formdata['name${keyValue - 1}'] = val;
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ));

    setState(() => ++_index);
  }

  Widget _buildidentificationtype1() {
    return FormBuilder(
      autovalidate: true,
      child: FormBuilderCustomField(
          attribute: "Identification type",
          validators: [FormBuilderValidators.required()],
          formField: FormField(
            builder: (FormFieldState<dynamic> field) {
              return InputDecorator(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                  labelText: 'Select Personal Identification type',
                  errorText: field.errorText,
                ),
                isEmpty: type == '',
                child: new DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                  child: new DropdownButton(
                    value: type,
                    isDense: true,
                    onChanged: (String newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        type = newValue;
                        field.didChange(newValue);
                      });
                    },
                    items: _type.map(
                      (String value) {
                        return new DropdownMenuItem(
                          value: value,
                          child: new Text(value),
                        );
                      },
                    ).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          )),
    );
  }

  Widget _builddocumentnumber1() {
    return new TudoTextWidget(
      controller: clrbusinesslicense,
      prefixIcon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.idCard),
      labelText: "Business License No",
      hintText: "Business License No",
      validator: Validators().validateLicenseno,
      onSaved: (val) {
        _licenseno = val;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildexpirydate1() {
    return FormField(builder: (FormFieldState state) {
      return DateTimeField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: expirydate1.toString(),
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.date_range)),
        format: format,
        onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) async {
          final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
              context: context,
              initialDate: expirydate1,
              firstDate: DateTime(1900),
              lastDate: DateTime.now());
          if (picked != null && picked != expirydate1)
            setState(() {
              expirydate1 = picked;
              print(expirydate1);
            });
        },
      );
    });
  }

  Widget _buildissuingauthority1() {
    return new TudoTextWidget(
      prefixIcon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.idCard),
      labelText: "Photo Identification issuing authority ",
      hintText: "Photo Identification issuing authority ",
      validator: (val) => Validators.validateName(val, "Issuing Authority"),
      onSaved: (val) {
        illusingauthority = val;
      },
      controller: clrissuingauthority,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("BSP Unlicensed Signup"),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          onPressed: () {
            NavigationHelper.navigatetoBack(context);
          },
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: _add)],
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Form(
          autovalidate: true,
          key: _formKey,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              // Background(),
              SingleChildScrollView(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                child: new Container(
                  child: new Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      _buildidentificationtype1(),
                      _builddocumentnumber1(),
                      _buildexpirydate1(),
                      _buildissuingauthority1(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flutter is a declarative UI framework and not a imperative one. You will not imperativitly create the new field.

The Flutter (declarative) way of doing this is when clicking a button change the state of your widget and call setState, when the widget is rebuild it will take in considerations your change on the state and it will build your new component. To sumarize you can do something like this:

```
//initialize with false
isClicked = false;

_add() {
  setState(() {
   isClicked = true;
  })
}

isClicked ? _buildidentificationtype1() : Container(),
isClicked ? _builddocumentnumber1() : Container(),
isClicked ? _buildexpirydate1() : Container(),
isClicked ? _buildissuingauthority1() : Container(),
```

Comment: but it will add only once
have you any other solution that will add field every time when i am click on add button? If you can help me please help me

Comment: If you want to add every time you have to change a bit. In this case you could create a List of widgets variable, and every time you press the button you add widgets to the end of the list and call setState again. Last but not the least you consume the list of widgets on your build method

Comment: Can you please help me to do it. Can you please update answer it's my request

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: MyHomePage(),
 );
}
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
 }

 class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 List<Item> itemList = [
 Item("ID1", "First product"),
  Item("ID2", "Second product"),
 ];

  Map<String, int> quantities = {};

  void takeNumber(String text, String itemId) {
  try {
  int number = int.parse(text);
  quantities[itemId] = number;
  print(quantities);
 } on FormatException {}
  }

 Widget singleItemList(int index) {
Item item = itemList[index];

return Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(flex: 1, child: Text("${index + 1}")),
      Expanded(
        flex: 3,
        child: TextField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          onChanged: (text) {
            takeNumber(text, item.id);
          },
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: "Qty",
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
 }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Demo")),
    body: Center(
      child: ListView.builder(
         shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: itemList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
           if (itemList.isEmpty) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else {
             return singleItemList(index);
           }
         }),
        ),
      );
    }
   }

  class Item {
  final String id;
  final String name;

  Item(this.id, this.name);
   }
```

Comment: Can you please explain to me what you've done in this code??

Comment: in my example, you can get any number of the text field using array dynamically